# Is there a way to simulate iPHone "Home" button press and relaunch the application throught javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, cocoa, automation

I'm automating an iPhone application, and I want to simulate the Home button press to close the app and re-launch the same app.

Tool used : Instruments
Script    : Javascript

Is it advisable for me to use

```
exit(0);
```

in javascript ?

If so how do I relaunch the application using Instruments

Please suggest

Comment: Are you talking about an actual iPhone natively run app?

Comment: No Kriem. I am automating an application which is installed manually. Is there a way to simulate Home button press and relauch app for iPhone native app ?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that using public API's.

Comment: What does this have to do with Instruments or JavaScript? Are you sure you even know your way around the iOS SDK?

Comment: I am using JavaScript to just automate the iPhone application test cases(I'm not developing iPhone app in Objective C). I am using Instruments as the tool to link the app and the script. So I am in need of some help for this :)

Comment: @Kiran Koundinya: I'm confused. You're using Instruments and JavaScript to script an application written by somebody else?

Comment: @Peter : Yup... You are almost there. I work for a s/w company which has developed an iPhone product in Objective C. I am automating the manual test cases for that product using the Instruments tool(Available in Mac) and the scripting language used is JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Only available way as far as i know is to put app in background for designated amount of seconds with command:

```
UIATarget.localTarget().deactivateAppForDuration(30);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is method in java-client `runAppInBackground()`